# Which texture does glGetTexLevelParameteriv check?

Tags: opengl

So I found the following definition:

```
void glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GLenum target, GLint level, GLenum pname, GLint* params);
```

where target is GL_TEXTURE1D, GL_TEXTURE2D, ... and level is the level of detail you would like to query where 0 is the base level. The 3rd parameter would indicate which property you would like to know and the final parameter is the return value. Here's my question:

Am I to assume this looks for the last binded texture of the given target? If not, would it look into the default texture object's state and return those values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It queries the texture object bound (see [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml)) to the given target in the currently active texture unit (see [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml)). This is how all non DSA OpenGL functions work.

Comment: Great just wanted to confirm that.